# Git remove previous made commit, but keep future commits with merges

Tags: git, rebase

I have this kind of tree in Git:

[image]

Now I want to remove commit `8a22e56e5`, but keep all future changes and merges.

Command `git rebase -i -p ed36940de`, but it will throw error `error: commit 1e5c47382 is a merge but no -m option was given`.
How to do it properly?

Comment: You probably need [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) for this case. I'm not writing an answer because I don't have time to test it myself.

Comment: The new (2.19-ish) `--rebase-merges` can be used for this but I'm hesitant to *recommend* it, and don't really have time to go into detail.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a shot and let us know how it goes:

```
git rebase -p --onto a6b8cff52 ed36940de 4510e25da
```

I have never tried to do something like this but that's what I would try to run.